# How to use CommandLineParser in a WinForms Project? How to build a custom Help MessageBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use the `CommandLineParser` Library in Version 2.5.0 in a WinForms application.

It works great except for a help screen (MessageBox in that case).

I already figured out that I need to create a own parser and set at least the `HelpWriter` property to `null` to create a custom Help Screen.

But when the application is called with `--help` argument my "Error handler" just get one error instance with a `Tag` of type `CommandLine.ErrorType` and a Value of `HelpRequestedError`

Now how to build the custom Help Screen?

https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Generating-Help-and-Usage-information

This site suggests to use the Types in CommandLine.Text Namespace but how? There are zero examples how to do it.

Anyone here did something like this?

I have the following code:

```
namespace myWorkspace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using CommandLine;
    using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
    using Options;

    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        internal static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "bin";

            WindowsFormsSettings.EnableFormSkins();
            WindowsFormsSettings.EnableMdiFormSkins();

            WindowsFormsSettings.ForceDirectXPaint();

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var parser = new Parser(config =>
            {
                config.AutoHelp = true;
                config.AutoVersion = true;
                config.CaseInsensitiveEnumValues = false;
                config.CaseSensitive = false;
                config.EnableDashDash = true;
                config.HelpWriter = null;
                config.IgnoreUnknownArguments = true;
                //config.MaximumDisplayWidth
                config.ParsingCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            });

            return Parser.Default.ParseArguments<RunOptions>(args)
                  .MapResult(
                             RunRunAndReturnExitCode,
                             RunParsingFailedAndReturnExitCode);
        }

        private static int RunRunAndReturnExitCode(RunOptions opts)
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Run(new MainForm());
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        private static int RunParsingFailedAndReturnExitCode(IEnumerable<Error> errs)
        {
            foreach (var err in errs)
            {
                var locErr = err;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And on Line `var locErr = err;` i don't know what to do to get a help screen message i can show in a MessageBox or the like.

`CommandLineParser` seems to support console output out-of-the-box for `help` or `--help` but I have no console app here.

Comment: Please post the code you have that isn't working

Comment: @amura.cxg I edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i now figured out a way to do it. Does not seem to be the best way but it works.

I create a `StringBuilder` instance and put it into a `StringWriter` instance

```
private static StringBuilder helpTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
private static StringWriter helpTextWriter = new StringWriter(helpTextBuilder);
```

Then I create a new Parser with (at least this) Option(s):

```
var parser = new Parser(config =>
{
    config.HelpWriter = helpTextWriter;
});
```

In the case of error I can now use what is written into the `helpTextBuilder` to show a message box.

```
private static int RunParsingFailedAndReturnExitCode(IEnumerable<Error> errs)
{
    MessageBox.Show(helpTextBuilder.ToString());
    return 1;
}
```

So this is now working for me.